# Text and buttons outgrow popup box size

Tags: html, css

A legacy website that I am working on has a popup box that uses an iFrame and has nested tables. Within the cells of this table there is simple text and the last row of the table has two input boxes; one left aligned and one right aligned.

On screen resolution higher than 1024 X 768 everything is displayed within the borders of the box. The problem lies when I have resolution of 1024 X 768 or lower the text expands wider then the box and therefore horizontal scroll bars are turned on. I like to modify the inline css styling that so prominent in this design so the text and buttons render the same in any resolution and no scroll bars are turned on.

The only thing I can see is that table width is set to 100%.

Any help will be a life saver.

Thanks

Please find screenshots attached:

**> 1024 x 768 sample**
[image: Greater than 1024]
**1024 X 768**

[image: 1024 x 768]

Here is the markup for the tables

```
<div align="center" style="padding: 8px 10px 4px;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="600px">
<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"> 
              <div class="container">
    <TABLE cellSpacing="5" cellPadding="5" width="100%" class="gradientHeader">
        <tr>
            <th width="100%">
                xxxxxx
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%">
                some text
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" style="PADDING-LEFT: 10px">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                        <FIELDSET style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none;padding:0;">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList id="rbl" runat="server" />
                        </FIELDSET>
                            </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td  align="left">
                    <AN IMAGE BUTTON>                       
                        </td>
                        <td  align="right">
                            <AN IMAGE BUTTON>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidProductId" id="hidProductId">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: I have edited my question with some of the markup, thx

Comment: What css is defined for the container class?

Comment: @kingjiv Here is the definition of container class:  { border: 1px solid #DADADA; margin: 10px 0 15x; padding: 3px;}

Answer (score 1):

the table code you have given, will only scroll once a width less than 600px is reached because of the very first fixed width table

there is an error in colspans the cell with the fieldset in it should be `colspan="2"` and there is too much `width="100%"` there would be no need to put it every cell once the table is set to 100%.. however even with those there's nothing here that would force a scrollbar until `<600px`

I think the problem must be the width of the `popup div` and/or `iframe` instead

Comment: Thx for points you picked out, I checked the iFrame using Firebug and this is how it is styled: #iframeIntercept {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 99%;
  height: 96%;
  background: none repeat scroll
    0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

Comment: Any recommendations on how to fix this instead of using such rigid, ugly hard coded values would be great help

Comment: the "popup div" is defined as follows: #overlay {
  margin: auto;
  left: 20%;
  top: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 105;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 3px 11px;
  background: url("../images/login_containerbg.jpg") repeat-x scroll
    0% 0% rgb(187, 203, 226);
  font: 12px arial;
  color: white;
}

Comment: here's all that code in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/NttKg/) - I presume the actual table code is in a separate page and what the iframe would be presenting? still give or take a few pixels - as you can see I can't reproduce, the iframe would really need to have a min-width of 600px on it too to make sure it always contains the tables, but it will depend on if there's any other CSS applied to the iframed page, some things to try (on the iframed page) remove, html, body padding and margin and ensure the tables are left aligned not centered, is the container div